# Verification before creating a user in RegistrationController

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In this Laravel script, when a user puts his details for registration, Laravel first creates the user, then sends an email for verification, I, on the contrary, want this action:
I want after the user puts his details, Laravel sends the email verification and if the verification is successful, creates the user.

The RegistrationController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\GeneralSetting;
use App\Service;
use App\ServicePrice;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default, this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/

use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = 'user/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'username' => 'required|string|alpha_dash|max:25|unique:users',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $general = GeneralSetting::first();
        $code = str_random(6);
        if($general->email_verification == 1){
            $ev = 0;
            send_email($data['email'], $data['name'], 'Verification'
            ,'Your code is'.':' . $code);
        }else {
            $ev = 1;
        }
        $api = str_random(30);
         $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'verification_time' => Carbon::now(),
            'verification_code' => $code,
            'email_verify' => $ev,
            'api_key' => $api,
        ]);
        $services = Service::all();
        foreach ($services as $service){
            $servicePrice = new ServicePrice();
            $servicePrice->category_id = $service->category_id;
            $servicePrice->service_id = $service->id;
            $servicePrice->user_id = $user->id;
            $servicePrice->price = $service->price_per_k;
            $servicePrice->save();
        }
        return $user;

    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification)

Comment: How/where would you store the new users information while waiting for their verification if not in the database?

Comment: In users table, each user has a column called "email_verify"
When the user is registered, the value of this column is 0
And when the user verified his email, the value changes to 1 and then they can access the panel

Answer (score 0):

When user sign up, the information which He provide is store in the `users` Table at least you set the `$table`  property of the model to something else. And the fact of saving users informations in the tables is part of the user registration process. It seams weird the fact that you want to register the user only after he verify his email address. My advice It will be to not log the user after he signed up and redirect him to another page even if he try to login you will set the loggin condition to log only user who has his email address verified.

Comment: I know this, but my main problem is to change the user's email
Now if the user fails to send the wrong email, he can not go back and edit it
On the other hand, this was made by Usernin
This means that the user will have to register again with another user with a valid email

I want to do this, until the user has confirmed their email, its profile is not saved

Comment: I have on question, how do you supposed to keep user informations if you doesn't save his data when he signed up? Another advice is even if the user doesn't verify is email you keep his data but after certain Hours or days. You have some [Queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues) which will be executed and remove all user who email are still not verified

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a feature similar to how password reset works.

You can leave your create method as is. There is also a register() function inside your RegisterController.

**1.** In that function you should override the part where the user gets logged in and instead you should redirect him to a page with a message saying that an email has been send and he needs to verify it.

Now as i see you send a **code** with the email.

**2.** You should also provide a link inside the email that redirects the user to a code submission page.

**3.** If you dont have a page like that you should create one. A blade file, a function to view it and a route on your web.php file to access it.

**4.** Inside that page you will have a `<form>` with one `<input>` field e.g. 'code' where its action will point to a function you will create e.g. validateCode() inside your RegisterController.

Then this functions job will be to check on the Users table for a user with a code same with the one provided from the request, if such a user exists then it will update the 'email_verify' field to 1 loggin in the user and redirect him to the panel, if not the it will redirect back to code submit view:

```
public function validateCode(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::whereVerificationCode($request->get('code'))->first();
    if($user){
        $user->verify_email = true;
        $user->update();
        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }else{
        return redirect()->back();
    }    
}
```

Also it would be good if you change the code your are generating to a 9 or 10 digit one or even better to a hashed string for security reasons.